# How to add a menu item in a xaml file

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0

I am new in silverlight ..
unlike windows form ,I am unable to find menu item in silverlight .
How to add menu item in xaml file.
I have to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in types that allow you to define a menu declaratively.  Even if you consider the Silverlight Toolkit you will still not find one.  You can do a web search on "menu silverlight" and you'll find a number of examples, including a couple on codeplex.

You might wonder why there isn't a native one or at least why the toolkit team haven't added one.  I can't claim to know the reasons myself but I'm glad they haven't.  Implementing a menu isn't that difficult in Silverlight and not having a "defacto" one has at least 2 advantages:-

1. Causes designers to consider whether one is really needed or whether there is a better way to deliver operations and navigations in the UI.
2. More likely to result in innovative and engaging menu solutions, we don't really want to see "File Edit" at the top of a Silverlight app.